# Passing MySQL functions to Eloquent ORM query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to execute the following query in Eloquent ORM and cannot seem to execute the MySQL function -

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->where('YEAR(created_at)', '=', $year)->first();
```

The exception I am getting is as follows - 
Message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEAR(created_at)' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `slug` = ? AND `YEAR(created_at)` = ? LIMIT 1

Bindings: array (
  0 => 'placeholder',
  1 => 2013,
)
```

So, basically, it is encapsulating the `YEAR()` MySQL function as a column. Is there any way to do this without using a raw query?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly by YEAR(created_at)?
And what is the value of ''''$year'''' usually?

Comment: `$year` would be just that - a variable with the year, such as 2013. `created_at` is a MySQL timestamp column, `YEAR(created_at)` would return `2013`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to use the `YEAR()` function in your WHERE clause anyway.  This would prevent you from using any index on the `created_at` column.  I would suggest you use `LIKE` instead:

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->where('created_at', 'LIKE', $year . '%')->first();
```

You can also just use raw SQL queries as well (using `query()` method) if you had need to utilize unsupported MySQL functions in your queries.

Comment: I'm aiming to have a URL along these lines = http://example.com/blog/2013/01/01/blog-post, so I need some way to dissect the `created_at` column to filter the year, month, and day.

Comment: OK, but what does that have to do with the question?  It seems your query was simply looking for the first post with a certain slug and a year and return the first one. If you needed to sort on Year and month, you would just change the like condition to `$year . '-' . $month` if you have the day value, you can add that as well (or perhaps just use `=` at that point of the DB field is a date field). It is probably not meaningful to do a WHERE on the month or day only, so just build your date criteria from left to right, allowing you to use the index on the field (you do have index right?)

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the possibility of pulling a post with a duplicate slug, that's the goal here.

Comment: @NightMICU Why would you not just put a unique index on `slug` and just lookup using that value?  Or treat the entire URI as a slug (again with unique index)?

Answer (score 35):

To prevent Eloquent ORM from wrapping first variable with apostrophes, you can use `DB:raw` function like:

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), '=', $year)
        ->first();
```

And you'll get query:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `slug` = ? AND YEAR(created_at) = ? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This 3 years old post save my life today. Thank you so much good sir :-)

Comment: This post help me when struggling on save data using mariadb dynamic column, thanks sir!

Comment: @ImamAssidiqqi this post from ULazdins also saved me - and it's 2023.

Answer (score 4):

You have two ways to do this and its depend on your laravel version

First use **Raw** method to pass function as below example

```
$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)
     ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), $year)
     ->first();
```

ِAlso you can use it in (select,group,order) Methods, for more information about Raw [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) its start from v 4.2

Second use **whereYear** Method

```
$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)
      ->whereYear('created_at', $year)
      ->first();
```

This method start from V 5.3 for more information [Read Where section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)  you will found all methods for dates (whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear)

Answer (score 1):

I use Laravel 5.3

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)->first();
```

This guy helped me >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32843415/7752468

Comment: [Stack Overflow generally works in English](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it.