# How to select year and month from the created_at attributes of database table in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

My problem is that I want to get data form the database table from the `created_at` attributes as per year and month only. The code I have tried is:

```
$post= Mjblog::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'));
$posts_by_y_m = $post->where('created_at',$post)->get();
```

Comment: You mean that your return results should contain all the years and months of the given **Mjblog** model, if yes, then why are you doing this: `$post->where('created_at',$post)->get();`?

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: My exact need is when I would click on archive month and year need to display the content of database table where there is created_at date field.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There are date helpers available in the query builder:

```
$post = Mjblog::whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)
              ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)
              ->get();
```

Comment: You can use `->whereMonth('created_at', $month)` also. Both will work.

Answer (score 13):

## *Performance Review*

Although the accepted answer may solve the OP problem but that is ***NOT*** the ***OPTIMAL SOLUTION*** in terms of database performance.
Because when `whereYear()` or `whereMonth()` helper is applied to query the records, it makes the query ***Non-[SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)***. This means if the compared column `created_at` is indexed in database then this index is ignored while searching the data. See **[`What makes a SQL statement sargable?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)**

Consider following expression

```
$posts = Mjblog::whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)
               ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)
               ->get();
```

The resultant query will be like

```
select * 
from mjblog 
where year(`created_at`) = :year 
  and month(`created_at`) = :month
```

The above query can be clearly seen as non-sargable because `year()` and `month()` functions are applied on `created_at` which produces a non index value.

To make it SARGable expression it's better to define the exact/range of values while comparing your indexed column. Like for OP the range can be derived from month and year values as

```
$year = 2000;
$month = 2;
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($year."-".$month."-01"); // universal truth month's first day is 1
$start = $date->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2000-02-01 00:00:00
$end = $date->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2000-02-29 23:59:59
```

Now the SARGable expression can be written as

---

```
select * 
from mjblog 
where created_at between :start and :end
```

Or

```
select * 
from mjblog 
where created_at >= :start 
  and created_at <= :end
```

In query builder it can be represented as

---

```
$posts = Mjblog::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
               ->get();
```

Or

```
$posts = Mjblog::where('created_at', '>=', $start)
               ->where('created_at', '<=', $end)
               ->get();
```

Another helpful article that highlights the cons of [**Non-SARGable Predicates & Anti-Patterns**](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/)

Comment: in simple question : Are you suggesting that this solution is way faster (in query time) then the accepted solutions?

Comment: @ToniTegarSahidi yes if `created_at` is indexed column this approach will utilize the added index the other one will neglect because year() and month() functions will be applied on query which will produce a new value other than indexed value

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid is right in his claim.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get the year and month from a single instance of `Mjblog` you can access them like this:

```
$year = $post->created_at->year;
$month = $post->created_at->month;
```

Read more about `Carbon\Carbon` [getters documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters]).