# How to get the YEAR of the created_at column inside the table using LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I'm trying to create a query that display all the driver's information and only get the "Year" in created_at column. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance

Here's the response query

```
        "user_id": 45,
        "driver_fname": "Sample",
        "driver_mname": "Sample",
        "driver_lname": "Sample",
        "driver_birthday": "2000-07-28",
        "years_driving_experience": null,
        "years_driving_experience_quicktrans": null,
        "start_year_of_exp_in_driving": null,
        "start_year_of_exp_in_driving_in_quicktrans": null,
        "educational_attainment": null,
        "health_status": null,
        "drug_test": null,
        "marital_status": null,
        "Salary_range": null,
        "license_registration": null,
        "license_expiration": null,
        "license_condition": null,
        "medication_maintenance": null,
        "training": null,
        "driver_height": null,
        "driver_weight": null,
        "weight_status": null,
        "emergency_contact_number": null,
        "home_address_street_number": null,
        "home_address_street": null,
        "home_address_brgy": null,
        "home_address_city": null,
        "work_hours_range": null,
        "work_shift": null,
        "sleep_hours_range": null,
        "smoker": null,
        "created_at": "2021-11-23 03:50:33"
```

the created_at column should be in Year, for example created_at:"2021"

Here is my query code

```
 $driversInformation = DriverInformation::all(['user_id','driver_fname','driver_mname','driver_lname',
        'driver_birthday','years_driving_experience','years_driving_experience_quicktrans','start_year_of_exp_in_driving',
        'start_year_of_exp_in_driving_in_quicktrans','educational_attainment','health_status','drug_test','marital_status',
        'salary_level As Salary_range','license_registration','license_expiration','license_condition','medication_maintenance',
        'training','driver_height','driver_weight','weight_status','emergency_contact_number','home_address_street_number',
        'home_address_street','home_address_brgy','home_address_city','work_hours_range','work_shift','sleep_hours_range','smoker',
        'created_at As year']);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select year and month from the created\_at attributes of database table in laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840698/how-to-select-year-and-month-from-the-created-at-attributes-of-database-table-in)

Comment: I already tried this but still it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to mutate the date in your `DriverInformation` model

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y',
];
```

You can read more about **mutators** here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query should be

```sql
select Year(createdAt) as Year from Persons;
```

you can check the example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5j8icfiw8nvwZdKqhtr4h/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon class ->
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('Y')

Comment: where should i put this code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).